# Why does net.socket.connect not work under Win10 (working under win7)?

Tags: c#, winsockets

using this code

```
IPEndPoint remoteEp = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
this._sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
this._sender.Connect(remoteEp);
```

to connect to an other computer works fine under win7.

With Win10 it throws an error:
[image]

Translation: No connection could be established because the target computer refused the connection.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Edit:
The firewall is off, ping is working, I use a distinct IP4-address, server ist running (and answers to a win7-machine properly).

With thanks in advance
Peter

Comment: sockets *itself* : does connect just fine - so I suspect this is a local configuration issue; it *could* be a firewall problem (at either end), or it could be an IPv4 vs IPv6 thing, or... just about anything else; or it could be subnets... can you ping between them? have you checked that the IP addresses are correct, and that the server is running? can you connect to the server port *from the same node*? etc

Comment: Have you checked the firewall settings for port 11000 on both machines?  The port may be whitelisted on the WIN7 machine but not on the WIN10 box.